# How to create nextjs getStaticPaths function using dynamic and nested paths (graphql)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How to create nextjs getStaticPaths function using dynamic and nested paths (graphql)?

I don't know how I can create the function correctly... Can someone help me? I am using Wordpress headless with graphQL

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const GET_ALL_SLUGS = gql`
    query getAllSlugs {
      posts {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
      pages {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `;
  const response = await client.query({
    query: GET_ALL_SLUGS,
  });

  const categories = response?.data?.pages?.nodes;
  const posts = response?.data?.posts?.nodes;

  let paths = {
    params: {
      category: "",
      post: "",
    },
  };

  paths = categories.map(({ slug }) => {
    return {
      params: {
        category: slug,
      },
    };
  });

  paths = posts.map(({ slug }) => {
    return {
      params: {
        post: slug,
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```